# Will 18.04 update its kernel above 5.1?

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, kernel

I want to use Ubuntu on my new laptop https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/omen-by-hp-17-cb0000-laptop-pc/26122176/document/c06411586.

I should thus use latest LTS, which is 18.04.

But 18.04 kernel does not support my laptop's hardware (for example wifi card requires 5.1+). 18.04 is currently in its third release 18.04.3. Will 18.04 receive the official update with the kernel above 5.1, so I can use my laptop?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.4 will come out in February 2020. It will have the same kernel as 19.10, that is, 5.3. You can install Ubuntu 19.10 with kernel 5.3 now and upgrade to Ubuntu LTS 20.04 in April 2020, which will have a newer kernel.

Comment: The other question has the answer to my question. But you also filtered the specific answer in your comment, which would not be that easy to find out by myself. Thank you. Btw, I don't want to use 19.10, I heard it is not good for "production". I tried it, but my hardware does not work with it also.

Comment: If Ubuntu 19.10 does not work in your hardware, I doubt Ubuntu 18.04.4 will. You may want to ask a new question about 19.10 and the specific hardware you have that does not work. Or you may have to wait for 20.04 LTS.